# Сайт для телефонов, или чем рисовать?

Tags: веб-программирование, html, php, html5, javascript

Одна студенческая некоммерческая организация решила ближе к НГ сделать квест для своих участников. Под квестом понимается путешествие по ночному городу, решение загадок.

Для этого нужно сделать страницу, на которой команды могли бы вбивать ответы, видеть вопросы, видеть свой прогресс и прогресс других команд. Вроде бы, все просто. Старенький html + копейка php для работы с БД и простенькая БД.

Соответственно, на стороне сервера, видимо, будет БД с командами и паролями, с текстами вопросов и состоянием ответов для отображения состояния.

Но есть интересное условие: состояние команд должно отображаться 8ми свечами (у каждой команды свой 8-ми свечник, по свече на вопрос), и при решении 3его задания, у команды должна "загореться" 3яя свеча (а все остальные команды это увидеть).

Соответственно, надо:

- Все должно грузиться с телефонов, т.е. сайт должен читаться safari, firefox, IE (это же самые популярные браузеры iOS, Android, Windows Mobile?).
- Все должно есть минимум трафика, т.к. участники будут с телефонов и немало времени с плохим 3G.
- Картинки с подсвечниками команд при этом должны быть максимально красивой :)

Если бы не третий пункт, я бы просто сделал все без картинок. Но он есть, а я человек очень далекий от web разработки, поэтому вопрос: как это лучше реализовать?

Меня интересуют технологии, как подобное обычно реализуется, при помощи чего. Например, интернет говорит, что в HTML5 + javascript можно вообще рисовать в canvas, какие у этого есть минусы, быстро ли это? Можно ли загрузить картинки в кэш браузеров телефонов, чтобы потом гонять только размётку? Или я вообще не в ту сторону смотрю? Может быть, тут может идеально подойти flash, или он сильно грузит трафик? Если грузит, можно ли это обойти?

Понимаю, что вопрос размытый, но другого пока нет. Идеальный ответ тот, после которого у меня сложится представление о 2-3х самых популярных вариантах решения подобной задачи, с пониманием плюсов и минусов каждого варианта.

Answer (score 2):

JSом. Никак иначе, все равно я так понимаю разовый эвент, поэтому если например JS будет каждые 10секунд посылать запрос на сервер (смотреть статус свечей), одноразовую нагрузку переживете.

Comment: Да, эвент разовый.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что речь идет о 3х картинках (картинка огня, картинка фитиля, картинка 8ми свечника), которые будут лежать в кэше браузера после первого обращения. Затем JS будет опрашивать сервер периодически, получать для каждой команды из N команд состояние 8ми свечей (по сути N раз массив из 8ми bool-ов), и в зависимости от этого отрисовывать или картинку огня, или картинку фитиля напротив каждой команды?